# Replacing character within cstring - getting bad access

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Is it possible to replace a character from a c string after converting it from NSString via the UTF8string method?

For example take the code below. It is to format a string with particular rule.

```
- (NSString *)formatString:(NSString *)input {
    if (input.length==0) {
        return @"";
    }
    //code to determine rule
    ....
    ....
    // substitute output format with input characters
    if (rule) {
        input = [input substringFromIndex:prefix.length];
        char *string = (char *)[rule UTF8String];
        int repCount = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<rule.length; i++) {
            if (string[i] == '#') {
                if (repCount < input.length) 
                    string[i] = [input characterAtIndex:repCount++];//bad access
                else 
                    string[i] = ' ';
            }
        }
        NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCString:string encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     ...
     ... //do something with the output 
    return output;
    } else {
    return input;
    }
}
```

Initially string[0] has '#' and it should get replaced with the character in the input. This is not happening.

Comment: Could you please provide examples of rule prefix and input that you use?

Comment: I'm really sorry as I can't do that, its private :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, NO.  That buffer doesn't belong to you so leave it alone.

Comment: The funny thing is, I have this code which works in the earlier version of the app, even when I step through it now! But it is not working now :-D. By the way, I've seen your answers on string replacement in other threads, so I take your word for it.

Comment: @thandasoru It's undefined behaviour so could have broken at any time.  I would extract the string to a buffer (of `unichar` objects) and you can probably use the same algorithm using this buffer, which does belong to you.

Comment: I simply created an char buffer, copied the characters using a for loop and did the replacement using the new buffer, just like you said above and it worked like a charm!

Comment: @thandasoru Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues:

1. You are casting `UTF8String`, which returns a `const char *`, to `char *`. `UTF8String` is, by definition, returning a read-only string and you should use it as such. (You really should use casts sparingly, if at all. Certainly never use casts to override `const` qualifiers for variables.)

   If you want to perform this C-string manipulation, you have to copy the string to your own buffer. For example, use [`getCString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJGIEIE) or [`getCharacters`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-getCharacters_range_) methods (but only after you've created a buffer to receive them, and remember to add a character for the `NULL` terminator).
2. By the way, you're also returning `characterAtIndex`, which is a `unichar` (which can be larger than 8-bits), and using it in your `char *` buffer (8-bits per character). I'd be wary about mixing and matching those without being very careful. It is best to pick one and stick with it (and `unichar` offers a little more tolerance for those non-8-bit characters).
3. Perhaps you check for this earlier, but you're setting `string` to be those characters after the `prefix`, and then proceed to check the next `rule.length` number of characters. But, as far as I can tell, you have no assurances that `string` actually has that many characters left in it. You should test for that, or else that will also cause problems.

Personally, I'd retire this whole C-string algorithm and employ the appropriate `NSString` and/or `NSMutableString` methods to do whatever replacement you wanted, e.g. [`stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW7), [`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6), or the equivalent `NSMutableString` methods, [`replaceCharactersInRange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceCharactersInRange:withString:) or [`replaceOccurrencesOfString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:).